# php variables auto-appending with other characters

Tags: php, curl

```
$routeRequestContent = ...;

$ch = curl_init();

if(FALSE === $ch){
    throw new Exception("Failed to initialize curl");
}

$header = array();
$header[] = 'Content-type: application/json';
$header[] = 'Accept: application/json';

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $routeRequestContent);
$server_output = curl_exec($ch);

$server_output = json_decode($server_output, true);


if(!empty($server_output['data'])){
    $data = $server_output['data'];
    foreach($data as $value){
        print_r($value);
        $value['minutesToNext​'] = 'hey';
        print_r($value);
        die();
    }
}

curl_close($ch);
```

[image]

So I'm making a php curl request to an API. Within the loop all I'm doing is printing the first array within the data I get from the curl and attempt to manipulate an index's (minutesToNext) value . What I get back though when I print the array again is the same array but with a new index (not the intended one updated). The new index is just the old one appended with some characters.

Similarly, if I assign $value['minutesToNext'] to a variable, it will not work. Nothing will get assigned. So essentially I can't use the return data at all. I have attempted to sanitize the return result, but nothing as worked. I've been able to parse out the keys and values of the return result and "dynamically" assign variables from the keys, but for some reason the variables will get appended with those same exact characters. Any idea? I believe there is something wrong with the data I get from the curl, but I can't seem to fix it.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I believe there is something wrong with the data I get from the curl

No, everything is fine with that.

It *can't* have anything to do with that data - because the *key* is specified by you, in your script:

```
$value['minutesToNext​'] = 'hey';
```

When I simply copy&paste that from here into a Hex editor, it shows that there's byte values `e2 80 8b` directly between `minutesToNext` and `'`, and that is the UTF-8 representation of a [zero-width space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_space) character.

It's likely gotten in there via copy&paste, maybe from some website (zero-width spaces are sometimes inserted by authors/CMS when code is displayed in HTML, to control line break behavior) ... mark the whole `'minutesToNext​'` text in your editor, re-type it ... and you should be fine.

(Plus you should to pass the value per reference in the foreach loop, as Magnus said in comments, good catch.)

Comment: You are correct! I copied the index/keys from the api itself, and they came with these extra characters. I would never I have caught this by myself. Thank you from the bottom of my heart!